# Field Extensions as $F$ adjoin some element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $E$ an extension of $F$. Is it always possible to write $E=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)$?

If $E$ is a finite extension then I think it is possible to write $E=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$. My reason is that if we take $\alpha\in E$ then as $[E:F]<\infty$  for some $n$ we must have $\alpha^n\in\text{Span}\{\alpha, \ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$. Meaning that $\alpha$ satisfies an (irreducible) polynomial in $F[x]$. If we keep doing this for each element in $E$ then we get $E=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$. Is this correct?

What about the case when $E$ is not a finite extension?

Thanks

Comment: Is $E$ an *algebraic* extension of $F$?

Comment: Does it matter whether it is algebraic or not? For example: if it is algebraic, then can I write it as $F(\alpha_1,\ldots)$. And not when it is not algebraic.

Comment: You can have transcendental extensions.

Answer (score 5):

An example  is  $\mathbb R$ as  extension of  $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: +1 Presumably you proffer this as a *counterexample*, i.e. a field extension that cannot be generated by adjoining countably many elements?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : exactly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $\Bbb{R}$ is not an algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, if we require that our $E/F$ is algebraic but not finite can we say that $E$ is $F$ adjoined a **countable** number of elements?

Comment: @BenjaminLim: I think that, if we select $F=\mathbb{R}(x)$ with $x$ transcendental over the reals, i.e. $F$ is the field of rational functions with real coefficients, then the extension field $E=F(\{\sqrt{x-a}\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\})$ "probably" cannot be gotten by adjoining a countable number of elements. Yet $E/F$ is algebraic. I don't have a proof though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hmmmm perhaps I should ask on MO?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99336/is-every-algebraic-extension-e-of-a-field-f-obtained-by-adjoining-a-countable

Comment: @BenjaminLim: I think that my "counterexample" should be seen as an analogue of adjoining square roots of distinct primes to the rationals - to get all those square roots you need them all. The proofs for those might carry over to this case, where we have an "uncountable set of primes of the form $x-a$". The reason the standrad proofs might work is that each individual element of the extension field only involves a finite subset of those square roots, so...

Answer (score 2):

When $E$ is a finite extension of $F$ we can always do this. For suppose that $[E:F] = n$. Then this means that we can choose $\alpha_1 \in E \setminus F$. Now consider $F(\alpha_1)$ as a subspace of $E$. As a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space it is finite dimensional so that $F(\alpha_1)/F$ is a finite extension. Now if $[F(\alpha_1):F] = n$, then we are done because $E = F(\alpha_1)$. Otherwise if it is less than $n$, we repeat this procedure again and find $\alpha_2 \in E \setminus F(\alpha_1)$ and look at $[F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2):F] = [\big(F(\alpha_1)\big)(\alpha_2):F]$. Eventually we will stop because $\dim_F E$ is finite, so that

$$E = F(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n)$$ for some $\alpha_1,\ldots \alpha_n \in E$.

**Edit:** Qiaochu has posted an example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99336/is-every-algebraic-extension-e-of-a-field-f-obtained-by-adjoining-a-countable) on MO to show that it is not true that every algebraic extension is obtained by adjoining a countable number of elements.

Comment: Yes I agree Ben. What about the case when $E/F$ is algebraic but not finite? Can we write $E=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)$ for some countable set of element $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots\}$?

Comment: @Sebastian Hmmm I am not so sure about that. Would you like to meet tomorrow at the library to discuss things?

Comment: @Sebastian Please see my edit. I have crossposted this on MO.

Answer (score 0):

If $E/F$ is a finite extension, then $E$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ with some basis $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ and thus $E = F(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$.